# Is this crystal defect an example of dislocation or a vacancy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, education, material-science

[image: What is the crystal defect in the middle of the image]

It looks to me that a regular hexagonal pattern formed by the Ga atoms is interrupted in the middle of the crystal. Is this a void (or vacancy...), dislocation or another type of defect?

Plus what viewing direction is it?

Answer (score 4):

It is an *edge dislocation*. Compare:

[image]

to:

[Detailed formation processes of stable dislocations in graphene](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2014/nr/c4nr04718d#!divAbstract)

Notice that the yellow loops have 5 and 7 edges, respectively, compared to the usual six.

Comment: Great! I identified the loop with 7 edges but could not tell what type of defect it is.

Comment: Is the viewing direction 0001?